# What is the best way of querying this field in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, binary

So I have a field in an elasticsearch index that indicates what groups a user is part of through a simple string field containing up to four binary values like so:

> 11 = Group 1 & 2
>
> 0001 = Group 4
>
> 101 = Group 1 & 3
>
> .... you get the idea

Now, I have a UI that allows users to enter a search for a field, and can add multiple groups, for example:

Group 3 - this would equal the following possibilities:

> 001 0011 011 0111 101 1011 111 1111

Groups 2 & 3 - these possibilities:

> 011 0111 111 1111

As you can see, when a user enters a group, it doesn't mean exclusivly that group, but that the user has *at least* got the searched for membership.

Now I am trying to build the JSON query in java for how best to query this. At the moment, a previous developer has written a pretty inefficient java method that creates a match statement for each of the possibilities. It produces this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "scp":  "001" }},
        { "match": { "scp": "0011"   }}..etc
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I should clarify, what I'm trying to improve is not just the elasticsearch query, but how to write it in Java without a huge IF statement for each of the possibilities.

Comment: is the "scp" field stored as a number or a string? If it's a string good luck with a bit mask. Personally I don't know why you don't just store the group names in an array and then do a simple term match against it. But if you're fixed on storing as a number where each bit represents a specific group, you could do a script query to bit mask against the field.

Comment: you're storing the groups in a way that makes querying hard. Have you considered storing in a way that makes it _easy_?

Comment: @Kevin , so it's stored as a String. Unfortunately, I have no control over the way the data is stored, I realise there are many better ways than this.
A script query sounds interesting, I'll look into that now.

Comment: Hey @Wayneio, so I think a script query will work, but I think you should also find a creative way to store the data differently. For example, its pretty common for data to exist in one format in a serving store (sql, mongo, whatever) which you have no control over, but there's no rule that says you have to dump the data exactly as it appears there into elastic for indexing. Usually I'll actually transform the data into a format that makes querying both efficient and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query like:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "scp" : [001, 0011, ...]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I've also clarified in my question, that it's not just about improving the JSON query that is sent to elasticsearch, but how to actually write it in Java in that it's not a ton of IF statements with all the possibilities